# Display newly added form element at the bottom

Tags: forms

I altered a form, and I added a `$form['priorities']` form element.

Why is it appearing right after the title form element, and not at the bottom of the form? How can I make it at the bottom?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can assign #weight attribute for that. I mean when you alter form assign #weight to your new field and give their weight last compare to other component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like KrishaWeb said you need to add a [#weight attribute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#weight) to your new element.

It would look like:

```
$form['priorities'] = array(
  ...
  '#weight' => 99,
  ...
);
```

You can also set weights on the other form elements so the form is explicitly in order.